# gen_udp in Elixir fails to connect to a UDP socket

Tags: sockets, udp, elixir, graphite, graphite-carbon

I'm trying to make [Graphitex](https://github.com/msoedov/graphitex) (a Graphite Carbon API client for Elixir) use `gen_udp` instead of `gen_tcp`.

The client is a GenServer that wraps a UDP socket, with a public API which is not related to the question.

The offending bits seem to be `connect/1`, `terminate/2` and `handle_cast/2` GenServer callbacks.

Original implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/msoedov/graphitex/blob/master/lib/graphitex/client.ex#L68), my fork is [here](https://github.com/filalex77/graphitex/blob/udp/lib/graphitex/client.ex#L68).

What I did:

- replaced `:gen_tcp.connect(host, port, opts)` (where `host` and `port` are those of a remote Graphite Carbon UDP endpoint) with `:gen_udp.open(0, opts)` (to get an OS-chosen port)
- replaced `:gen_tcp.send(socket, msg)` with `:gen_udp.send(socket, host, port, msg)` to send `msg` to remote `host:port` via OS-chosen UDP socket

The error I get when running the app with my fork of `graphitex`:

```
12:12:14.160 [info]  Connecting to carbon at localhost:2003
12:12:14.383 [error] GenServer Graphitex.Client terminating
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Graphitex.Client.terminate/2
    (graphitex) lib/graphitex/client.ex:78: Graphitex.Client.terminate({{:badmatch, {:error, :econnrefused}}, [{Graphitex.Client, :connect, 1, [file: 'lib/graphitex/client.ex', line: 73]}, {Graphitex.Client, :handle_cast, 2, [file: 'lib/graphitex/client.ex', line: 86]}, {:gen_server, :try_dispatch, 4, [file: 'gen_server.erl', line: 637]}, {:gen_server, :handle_msg, 6, [file: 'gen_server.erl', line: 711]}, {:proc_lib, :init_p_do_apply, 3, [file: 'proc_lib.erl', line: 249]}]}, %{socket: nil})
    (stdlib) gen_server.erl:673: :gen_server.try_terminate/3
    (stdlib) gen_server.erl:858: :gen_server.terminate/10
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:249: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Last message: {:"$gen_cast", {:metric, 'graphite_consumer 1000 1570525934\n'}}
State: %{socket: nil}
```

It seems that the socket (that I clearly put in state in `connect/1`) is `nil`. I'm puzzled why can it be; `:gen_udp.open(0)` in IEx works fine and returns `{:ok, socket}`.

Comment: There is no such thing as connecting to a socket. You are failing to *send* to an *unconnected* UDP socket. This is not legal. You have to connect the socket to the target, or use `sendto()` or `sendmsg()`.

Comment: @user207421 Sorry, I don't get it. Do I need to add a step between `:gen_udp.open` and `:gen_udp.send`? There is `:gen_udp.connect/3`, but it's undocumented, and I'm not sure on how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UDP is connection-less protocol, which mean that you do not need to connect to the remote socket to send data. All you need to do is:

```
{:ok, socket} = :gen_udp.open(0)

:ok = :gen_udp.send(socket, host, port, msg)
```

No need for connecting, that is why there is no documentation for `:gen_udp.connect`, as it shouldn't be used at all.